# How to print a certain cell under a specific condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def analyze(entries):
    print(f'first entry: {entries[0]}')

with open("reddit_vm.csv", "r", encoding='UTF-8', errors="ignore") as input:
    entries = [(e['id'], int(e['score']), int(e['comms_num']), e['title']) for e in csv.DictReader(input)]
    avgScore = analyze(entries)

# highest score / title for that post

    highScore = max(score) # Find the highest score
    print("\nHighest score:")
    print(highScore)
    
    title = []
    title = [i[3] for i in entries]
    print("\nTitle for the Highest Scores:")   

    selected_column = [title, score]
    highTitle = title(score == highScore)
    print(highTitle)
```

This is some portion of my code in Python.
I need to find the title for the highest scores, and print it.
it is 'I would rage if this was handed to me...'.

So the expected output should be like this:

```
Title for the Highest Scores:
I would rage if this was handed to me...
```

This is the excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1glhNHkzKwHVqwuWbS8ajiNJR3H94Xw4W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what error it shows?

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded your csv and corrected your code 
I've written comments for you to understand your errors

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def analyze(entries):
    print(f'first entry: {entries[0]}')

with open("reddit_vm.csv", "r", encoding='UTF-8', errors="ignore") as input:
    entries = [(e['id'], int(e['score']), int(e['comms_num']), e['title']) for e in csv.DictReader(input)]
    avgScore = analyze(entries)

    # highest score / title for that post

    #   highScore = max(score) # Find the highest score
        #first error: what 'score'? what is this? you need to assign a variable first before reference it. 
    highScore = max([i[1] for i in entries])
    print(f'highest score: {highScore}')


    # title = []
        # what for do you need this line? it's absolute useless

    title = [i[3] for i in entries]             
        #here you've created list `title` with all titles 

    # print("\nTitle for the Highest Scores:")   
    # selected_column = [title, score]
        #here you create list with two elements 
            #firs element title list with all titles - so it's 2D list
            #sec element non-existing score variable 
    # highTitle = title(score == highScore)
        # in this line you actually run some `title()` function that doesn't exist 
        # and place bool of `score==highScore` that would be False if `score` would exist as func's arg


    #to get this:
        # Title for the Highest Scores:
        # I would rage if this was handed to me...
    # you'd rather use something like this: 
    entries.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
        #you sort `entries` in a way when the itep with the highest score will be placed as the last element in list. you can use `entries[-1]` to get it
    print('Title for the Highest Scores:')
    print(entries[-1][3])
```

it works as you wanted it to